# Why is addition to acid chloride favoured over SN2 at the carbon even though it has a Beta-carbonyl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

I feel that the conditions highly favour $S_\mathrm{N}2$ reaction at the aliphatic center and so the aliphatic chlorine should be replaced before the carbonyl chlorine. But the solution suggests that the nucleophilic substitution of carbonyl chlorine takes place before the aliphatic chlorine.

Comment: I would say this is down to basic electron density considerations. Look at which atoms are connected directly to each electrophilic carbon. The $\ce{COCl}$ carbon is connected to $\ce{C}$, $\ce{O}$ (double bond) and $\ce{Cl}$. The $\ce{CH2Cl}$ carbon is connected to $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{Cl}$. More generally, it is known that acid chlorides are more reactive than alkyl chlorides. The additional activation of this specific alkyl chloride by the proximity of the carbonyl does not change that. I am sure a physical chemist can answer more authoritatively, but I believe I am not far off the mark.

Comment: I had the same feeling too thanks for confirming it.